# What basic component am I missing from my signalR client?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, signalr

Following this tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

I managed to implement a really, really simple signalr chat client. That is, a hub that broadcasts the message sent to it from javascript.

Great, that works.

But now I've tried to create a second project with the same index.html file and js (i.e. the code that sends the message), and I'm getting an undefined error. The only difference between the file when it was as the tutorial specifies and as I've done (in the 'remote' project), is that I've explicitly specified the `connection.hub.url` as I've been advised to from various posts.

What exactly am I missing? It's obviously not enough to simply set the url to the other site hosting the signalr hub, do I need to add a proxy of some sort? Totally confused at this point.

My javascript file (the javascript on the website without the hub):

```
$(function () {
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:14113/signalr";

            chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
                // Do something
            };

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                });
            });
        });
```

It is on the first reference to the `chat` variable I have the undefined error.

NOTE: I can confirm both sites are running, the hub is available as I can navigate to the other tab (the same index.html file in the original solution) and it functions as expected.

I can also confirm the presence of my jQuery library (referenced correctly), and the jQuery signalR script (again, no 404s, all referenced correctly).

Comment: Are you including your hubs in your second project (something like <script src="http://localhost:14113/signalr/hubs"></script>)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access to the `chatHub` which is generated in your host application. And it looks like your code fails on getting that `chatHub`. You need to make sure that you are including hubs in your client application like so:

```
<script src="localhost:14113/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks again, can I ask - why can't I see signalr/hubs in the file system for the first site? I'll try this now, but I'll be surprised if I'm referencing something that doesn't exist - is there a handler for it or something?

Comment: Because hubs generated by Signalr based on all your c# classes that derived from Hub.

Comment: I think this has worked, I still can't work out where the signalr directory is on disk, but at least all I have now is some CORS access problems, I can solve those.

Comment: As I said you won't be able to find that directory as it generated when you request it (basically that is an action which returns javascript)

Comment: Sorted!! Thanks very much mate, really appreciate that. All working as I need it to.

Answer (score 1):

Try a proxy with `xdomain` such as

```
$(function () {

    $.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:14113/signalr';

    $.connection.hub.start({ xdomain: true })
        .done(function () { console.log('Connected. connectionId : ' + $.connection.hub.id); })
        .fail(function () { console.log('Could not connect!');
    });

    var proxy = $.connection.chatHub;

    proxy.client.broadcastMessage = function(uri) {
        //Do something
    };

    $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
        proxy.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
    });
});
```